# Spline coefficients in Scilab

Tags: interpolation, spline, scilab

I want to fit a piece-wise cubic spline to a large set of data. I don't think I want B-splines because I want the splines to go through the data points exactly. The only way I can see to do this in Scilab is with `splin` and `interp`.

However, I want to coefficients of each piece of the spline between the knot points (because I need to take these coefficients and put them in a different piece of software). All `splin` gives you is the derivatives. Is there a way to get the cubic spline coefficients? Or is there a way to generate the coefficients from the first derivatives easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one can get coefficients from the y-values you have and derivative values returned by `splin`. One each interval [x(i), x(i+1)] you have 4 coefficients to find, and 4 equations: values at both ends, derivatives at both ends. The most straightforward way is just tell Scilab to solve this 4 by 4 system for each subinterval: this should not take much longer than the evaluation of the spline itself. The program below does this.

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5]   // x values
y = [1,0,1,0,1,0]   // y values
d = splin(x,y)      
n = length(x)-1     // number of subintervals
cfs = zeros(4,n)    // matrix to store coefficients in
for i=1:n
    a = x(i)
    b = x(i+1)
    cfs(:,i) = [1,a,a^2,a^3; 1,b,b^2,b^3; 0,1,2*a,3*a^2; 0,1,2*b,3*b^2] \ [y(i);y(i+1);d(i);d(i+1)]
end
```

The first two equations `1,a,a^2,a^3; 1,b,b^2,b^3` relate the values of polynomial to the y-values; the other two `0,1,2*a,3*a^2; 0,1,2*b,3*b^2` do the same for its derivative. (The formulas are just derivatives of powers of x.)

The output of the above script:

```
    1.     1.   - 8.6    13.     13.   
  - 3.4  - 3.4    11.  - 10.6  - 10.6  
    3.1    3.1  - 4.1    3.1     3.1   
  - 0.7  - 0.7    0.5  - 0.3   - 0.3
```

Each column has the four coefficients: e.g., the first piece of the spline is `1-3.4x+3.1x^2-0.7x^3`. Since this is a not-a-knot spline, the default mode of `splin` command, the second piece is the same as the first; and last is the same as second-to-last.

You can check that this works correctly by plotting the pieces:

```
for i=1:n  
    t = linspace(x(i),x(i+1))
    plot(t,cfs(:,i)'*[ones(t); t; t.^2; t.^3])
end
```

---

That said, it would be easier to represent the polynomials forming the spline in the form

```
 p(x) = y(i) + A*(x-x(i)) + B*(x-x(i))*(x-x(i+1)) + C*(x-x(i))^2*(x-x(i+1))
```

where the coefficients are easy to find one by one, without solving a linear system:

- `A = (y(i+1)-y(i))/(x(i+1)-x(i))` by equating the value at x(i+1)
- `B = (d(i)-A)/(x(i)-x(i+1))`, by equating derivative at x(i)
- `C = (d(i+1)-A-B*(x(i+1)-x(i)))/(x(i+1)-x(i))^2`, by equating derivative at x(i+1)

Of course, then these coefficients should be used with the appropriate polynomials as above. Here is this alternative version

```
for i=1:n
    A = (y(i+1)-y(i))/(x(i+1)-x(i))
    B = (d(i)-A)/(x(i)-x(i+1))
    C = (d(i+1)-A-B*(x(i+1)-x(i)))/(x(i+1)-x(i))^2
    cfs(:,i) = [y(i);A;B;C]
end
// Again, plot for testing
for i=1:n
    t = linspace(x(i),x(i+1))
    plot(t,cfs(:,i)'*[ones(t); t-x(i); (t-x(i)).*(t-x(i+1)); ((t-x(i)).^2).*(t-x(i+1))])
end
```